# Html style text area format

Tags: html, asp.net, css

Hai i want the text should come at the bottom of the cell but it showing in the middle. Please help me to  solve this. i typed valign="bottom" in td but then also not coming at the bottom of the cell.

```
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="bottom"  style="padding-left: 20px; background-color: Green">
                <div style="padding-top: 5px">
                    <div  style="float: left">
                        First Name
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; font-size: 11px; padding-top: 2px">
                        (as in passport)
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; color: Red; padding-left: 1px">
                        *
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 20px">
                <div style="padding-top: 5px">
                    <div  style="float: left">
                        Last Name
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; font-size: 10px">
                        (as in passport)
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; color: Red">
                        *
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFEDF" Width="200px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 0px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFEDF" Width="200px" ></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: did you try setting an height to the td?

Comment: You can add "position: absolute" to the td, and "position: absolute; bottom: 0;" to each div

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon- Yes i tried but it's not coming

Comment: @maja--> Okay i'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add "`position: relative; bottom: -3px;`" to the div in the td's - it would just move them 3 px lower.
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLTRx/

Another possibility would be to make the small text being independent from the cell-content. The text would always stay at the same place: http://jsfiddle.net/h5Vzw/

But I would recommend you to put the whole styling in an external stylesheet, and to avoid style-tags.

Comment: @Zeeju: If this answer is good enough for your purposes, you should accept it.

Comment: @Zeeju: on the left side of the answer is a check mark. Right under the upvote and downvote arrows. When you click it, it turns green and the answer is marked as accepted

Comment: @maja-->i clicked  that green check box. when i click the up arrow it shows "upvote requires 15 reputation"